# How to play video one by one in TextureView in android?

Tags: android, android-textureview

I want to play the video one by one from my sdcard using Texture view in android. I am using tetureview bcoz , I want to rotate the video at 90 degree.. so I can play the rotated video on device by implementing **SurfaceTextureListener interface**.

This is the code:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    ArrayList extList = new ArrayList<String>();
    extList.add("mp4");
    extList.add("3gp");
    extList.add("ts");
    extList.add("webm");
    extList.add("mkv");
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    vFiles = b.getStringArrayList("vFiles");
    System.out.println("VFiles: " + vFiles);
    iterator = vFiles.iterator();
    videoPath = root + "/Video/";

    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Inside iterator: .......................................");
        String video = videoPath + iterator.next();

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        //mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
        //  afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(video);
        System.out.println("After Datasource: " + video);
        mMediaPlayer.setSurface(sur);
        //  mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        // mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener((OnBufferingUpdateListener) this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        // Play video when the media source is ready for playback.
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                //  mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But By this code, Only one video is playing , after another video is not playing.. and I want when one video is finished then second video in the list should be play and so on..

I searched a lot about this on net... But no luck...

Can any one help me regarding this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onSurfaceTextureAvailable` method doesn't get triggered when the `MediaPlayer` object has completed playback, it gets triggered when the Surface texture is ready to be used.

You need to implement `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener`, the `onCompletion` method gets triggered once the playback is completed.

Start the playback of the next video in the list once the playback of the first video is completed.

Comment: Hi, @bluefalcon, But,

Comment: @ArchanaSarang but ?? - you missed some text I guess :)

Comment: yes, but, my videos are not playing sequentially .. i have implement onCompletion method.. with calling finish method. It's just close the activity    . I want to play sequence of the videos..

Comment: Yes, `finish` method will close the activity. You don't want to do that. `onCompletion` method indicates the first video playback is completed, so now you can restart the `mediaplayer` object with the path to the new video and start the playback.